# Iterate over inner key: value in json and display

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following object:

```
response = 
    {
        "5": {
            "name": "surgeon bueno",
            "country": "Spain",
            "antiquity": "renewal",
            "amount": "2686.97 USD",
            "sellers": {
                "Frank": "2690.58 USD",
                "Bob": "1690.58 USD",
            }
        },
        "11": {
            "name": "Alex Lloyd",
            "country": "American Samoa",
            "antiquity": "new client",
            "amount": "0.0 USD"
        },
        "12": {
            "name": "alex lloyd",
            "country": "Aruba",
            "antiquity": "new client",
            "amount": "0.0 USD"
        }
    }
```

And I iterate over all values and display them in a new row in a table as follows, I would like to add a new row for those that have `"sellers"` in the JSON eg. like `"surgeon bueno"`, how can I iterate through them as well and display a new row if they exist? As they don't have key names.

```
  $.each(response, function(i, item) {
          $('#modal-table tbody').append("<tr><td>" + response[i].name + "</td><td>" + response[i].country + "</td><td>" + response[i].antiquity + "</td><td>" + response[i].amount);
       });
```

Comment: Is `item` not the same like `response[i]`? So why not using e.g. `item.name` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use the value parameter(item) of the each function

```
$.each(response, function(i, item) {
   $('#modal-table tbody').append("<tr><td>" + item.name + "</td><td>" + item.country + "</td><td>" + item.antiquity + "</td><td>" + item.amount);
});
```